# what are the different between 'not' and 'false'

Tags: logic, ocaml

What is the difference between

```
if mi.(j) = false && m.(j).(i) = false
```

and

```
if not (mi.(j) && m.(j).(i))
```

Because I think it has the same meaning, but when I run the code it gives me a different answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say `mi.(j)` is true and `m.(j).(i)` is false.

```
mi.(j) = false && m.(j).(i) = false
true = false && false = false
false && true
false

not (mi.(j) && m.(j).(i))
not (true && false)
not (false)
true
```

You probably want `not (mi.(j) || m.(j).(i))`.  This is basically
an instance of DeMorgan's laws.

Answer (score 5):

```
if mi.(j) = false && m.(j).(i) = false
```

is actually the same as

```
if not mi.(j) && not m.(j).(i)
```

which, by De Morgan's laws, is equivalent to

```
if not (mi.(j) || m.(j).(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if mi.(j) = false && m.(j).(i) = false  not equal to  if not (mi.(j) && m.(j).(i))
```

for

```
if not (mi.(j) && m.(j).(i))
```

you opposite the result of

```
  (mi.(j) && m.(j).(i))
```

'Not' does not means false but means opposite of the statement.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the basic question, there is not difference between `x=false` and `not x`.  Those two expressions will always, always, always produce the same result.  As others have pointed out, the actual problem with the two bits of code is a failure to recognize that you haven't used DeMorgan's laws.  The first version is equivalent to

```
(not m.(j)) && (not m.(j).(i))
```

which is not the same as

```
not ( m.(j) && m.(j).(i) )
```

I find that the best way to remember this sort of thing is to think of the real-world sentences.  If I were to say "I want a day where it's not raining and it's not snowing."  That's different from saying "I want a day where it's not both raining and snowing."  The sentence which is actually equivalent to the first one is "I want a day where it's neither raining nor snowing."  (i.e. not (raining or snowing)).  So, you have to keep that in mind with your logic as well.

This is why the equivalent to the first statement is

```
not ( m.(j) || m.(j).(i) )
```